# How to add locale data dynamically using React Intl?

Tags: react-intl, babel-plugin-react-intl

Am using React-intl for internationalization of an UI Util Library. The library has a folder say i18n wherein I place json files for different locales.If the user of this library want to add support for additional locales, he/she can place additional json file with key/value pairs for the respective locale.

But React-intl requires to import and addLocaleData for the respective locale in prior.For example,

```
import fr from 'react-intl/locale-data/fr';
addLocaleData([...fr]);
```

Is there a way to addLocaleData and import the locale library for the respective locale dynamically in React-intl?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Hey I have done this now, as described below and its working :-)

```
const possibleLocale = navigator.language.split('-')[0] || 'en';
addLocaleData(require(`react-intl/locale-data/${possibleLocale}`));
```

Here, the locale is fetched from the browser through navigator.language.
Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 9):

If you are using webpack. You can code-split the different locale data from your app and load dynamically. Webpack 1 supports only require.ensure() and webpack 2 also supports System.import(). System.import returns a promise while require.ensure uses a callback. https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

With System.import()

```
import { addLocaleData } from 'react-intl';

const reactIntlLocaleData = {
  fr: () => System.import('react-intl/locale-data/fr'),
  en: () => System.import('react-intl/locale-data/en')
};

function loadLocaleData(locale){
  reactIntlLocaleData[locale]()
  .then((intlData) => {
    addLocaleData(intlData)
  }
}
```

With require.ensure()

```
import { addLocaleData } from 'react-intl';

const reactIntlLocaleData = {
  fr: () => require.ensure([], (require) => {
    const frData = require('react-intl/locale-data/fr');
    addLocaleData(frData);
  }),
  en: () => require.ensure([], (require) => {
    const enData = require('react-intl/locale-data/en');
    addLocaleData(enData);
  })
};

function loadLocaleData(locale){
  reactIntlLocaleData[locale]();
}
```

Depending on your development environment the code above may or may not work. It assumes you are using Webpack2 along with Babel to transpile your code.

Comment: Is it possible to load the json file the same way ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same pattern as above to load the language json file.

Comment: @slchap5 Does this mean a single bundle will be created containing both `fr` & `en` locale data and loaded on the page via a script tag in your index.html ? Or will it just generate a bundle that can be loaded on runtime  when `loadLocaleData` gets called ?

Comment: @LoicUV Each `require.ensure` or `system.import` will create a new split point and bundle that code into a separate file that will be loaded at runtime.  So "Or will it just generate a bundle that can be loaded on runtime when loadLocaleData gets called" is correct.

Comment: @slchap5 Thx ! Also note that starting webpack v2.1.0-beta.28, `System.import()` is now replaced by `import()`